# Strings (by themselves) not permitted in JSON responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to understand what is incorrect with a JSON response being a string.

**Does not work:**

```
render json: "downgrade"
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0

**This works:**

```
render json: {recommendation: "downgrade"}
```

**This works:**

```
render json: ["downgrade"]
```

**Even this works:**

```
render json: 17
```

Why would an integer by itself work but a string would not? Or does `render json: "downgrade"` need to be written differently.

[Note: this is being sent from a Rails backend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render json: "downgrade"` outputs `downgrade`. As you can see there are no quotes around the string and thus, it is not a valid JSON string. It has to be `"downgrade"`.

When you print an integer, it outputs an integer, no quotes, no extra symbols, which is a valid JSON.

To make it work you need to force it to print those quotes. You can do it by adding `.to_json` at the end.

```
render json: "downgrade".to_json             # => "\"test\""
```

This would render a valid JSON data.

However, please note, `render :json` is [supposed to call `.to_json`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json) on objects automatically. But, as you can see it does not in this case.